# DateTime? AddDays Extension Method

Tags: c#, datetime, extension-methods

I want to write an extension method that adds one day to a Nullable DateTime, but modifies the date itself.

I want to use it as follows:

```
someDate.AddOneDay();
```

This directly changes the value of someDate.

The code I initially wrote was:

```
public static DateTime? AddOneDay(this DateTime? date)
{
    if (date.HasValue)
    {
        date.Value = date.Value.AddDays(1);
    }

    return null;
}
```

but this doesn't work since the reference is changed thus calling it this way
won't change the value of someDate.

Is there a way to achieve this and avoid code like:

```
someDate = someDate.AddOneDay();
```

Also I was thinking for some setter of the DateTime properties, but they don't have any..

```
public int Day { get; }
public int Month { get; }
public int Year { get; }
```

Comment: I wouldn't do that....

Comment: Is it a violation of some language rules?

Comment: _Well_, `DateTime` is an [immutable type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) in .NET Framework. You can't change it. As you can see in your code, you are assign `date.Value` property what `date.Value.AddDays(1)` returns.

Comment: So your goal is to confuse anyone who might misread your code and mistake it for the standard built in functionality?

Comment: No, I want to save me the time of writing 
someDate = someDate.HasValue? someDate.AddDays(1) : null;
to awful lot of places :) @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: @gyosifov If you have that code in an awful lot of places, perhaps you need to rethink your design. If the code smells, take the hint ;)

Comment: @dcastro You are probably right, but there is not a good way to detect those dates at runtime

Comment: Even if you have this so often that it's worth doing the extension, I'd strongly recommend that you make it resemble the methods on the underlying type - i.e. that you still treat the original as immutable and return the mutated value (also, probably, parameterize it in the same way as `AddDays`). Making it superficially resemble in-place mutation is likely to be harmful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't DateTime is immutable, and should stay that way.

Just do:

```
someDate = someDate.AddOneDay();
```

And if you want to be more specific, you could rename your function to:

```
DateTime? someDate = someDate.AddOneDayOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 3):

old school %)

```
public static void AddOneDay(ref DateTime date)
{
    if (date != null) date = date.AddDays(1);
}
```

usage:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
AddOneDay(ref date);
```

UPD

one line version of method:

```
public static void AddOneDay(ref DateTime date) { date = date.AddDays(1); }
```

Comment: The `if (date != null)` check is redundant: `DateTime` is a non-nullable struct, so will always have a value and hence will always be `!= null`

Answer (score 0):

C# does support a similar feature, even for mutable values, which is the use of `+=` on nullable values:

```
DateTime? date = GetDate();
var oneDay = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
date += oneDay;
```

Comment: You just added 2 lines, to a one line solution, that does the exact same thing, except now it's harder to spot what you are trying to do.

Comment: This won´t CHANGE the value of date, it will reference another one, so this is barely an answer to what the OP asked.

Comment: @André - What is the one line solution to adding a day to a nullable DateTime? Also, this just shows the feature. If you want to use that everywhere, you probably want `oneDay` to be a public value, and you could access it from anywhere.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - That is wrong. `DateTime` is not a reference type so it cannot "reference another one", it will change the value of the local `date` variable.

Comment: @Kobi Yes having a God object with a static global value is surely the way to go. Extension methods are there for a reason, to easily extend code so you avoid copypasta like you are suggesting.

Comment: @André - Please don't pretend that having `1` hardcoded in your extension method is any different than having it as a global constant. That's exactly the same. My suggestion is that anywhere in your code you can do `nextUserBirthday += DateConstants.OneDay;`. You suggested `nextUserBirthday = nextUserBirthday.AddOneDayOrDefault()`. I really don't see how one is better than the other.